# MySQL: Simple way to toggle a value of an int field

Tags: mysql

I know how to do this, but i think I'll overcomplicate it with double selects and so on.

How can you do this (example in pseudo-sql)

```
UPDATE some_table SET an_int_value = (an_int_value==1 ? 0 : 1);
```

It must be an int value due to some other functionality, but how do you do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
UPDATE some_table SET an_int_value = IF(an_int_value=1, 0, 1);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: How to pass an array to make the 0 and 1 dynamic

Answer (score 119):

```
UPDATE table SET field = 1 - field
```

Comment: Very simple mathematic logic, which is both wonderful and graceful at the same time. So awesome, hats off to you!

Comment: Difference between this and using `IF` is the way it behaves with `NULL`. Using `IF` null values are set to `1`, using this they stay `NULL`. Really depends what you want.

Comment: I like this solution because it works with other databases as well! (that don't have the IF function available)

Comment: I tried this on a signed column and `set 0 - 1` resulted in -1.

Comment: I just logged in to stack overflow only for upvoting this answer. awesome trick.

Answer (score 16):

```
UPDATE some_table SET an_int_value = IF(an_int_value=1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 11):

In this case, you could use an XOR type operation:

```
UPDATE some_table SET an_int_value = an_int_value XOR 1
```

This is assuming that an_int_value will always be 1 or 0 though.

Answer (score 4):

I can see the answers of all experienced people and i too got updated with their answers.

what about this...
i do this way...

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = not fieldname
```

can any body give suggestions please if this will not be a feasible solution. with respect to execution speed or any other... what to say... fact... concept... .

Comment: This works in MySQL, but only by coincidence and their nonstandard implementation of booleans as the integer 0/1.  This probably won't work on most other standard SQL implementations (though I have not tested it).

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
UPDATE some_table SET an_int_value = ABS(an_int_value - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TINYINT (0 and 1) then do a simply XOR (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor)

```
UPDATE
    `some_table`
SET
    `an_int_value` = `an_int_value` ^ 1
```

**Testing:**

SELECT 0 ^ 1; /* returns 1 */

SELECT 1 ^ 1; /* returns 0 */

Answer (score 0):

For ENUM(0,1) fields you can use...

UPDATE table SET int_value=BINARY(int_value=1)

Answer (score 0):

For ENUM(0,1) 
UPDATE some_table SET an_int_value = IF(an_int_value='1', '0', '1');

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?