# Permanent computed field mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replace an application with a different application. While the replacement is in place, we decided to try to use both at once, which means having both access the same database. There is one problem left. AppOld and AppNew access the same table of a database, let's say it's a user table. And AppOld has a field called `active` while AppNew has a field called `deactivated`. The rest of the table is identical.

So, that's kind of an ugly solution in which I could handle with changes to one of the applications, which is not ideal since I need to change the libraries that are used in this application that are using that table and the libraries are using other code. Or I need to add endpoints so that one application can actually call the other application.

And the extremely easy solution would a virtual field in MySQL. Something like that I could define like this: `active is not deactivated`. That would allow me to solve this issue with one ALTER TABLE. Now I wonder if that's even possible. I couldn't find anything suggesting that's possible so far, but better ask before adding a 6-hour workload.

And just for clarification: I cannot change the SELECT statements, because those are done by ORM which in turns are in libraries, that are used in different projects as well. So, I want to add a column that is defined by being the opposite of another column instead of saving values. I also cannot call stored procedures for the very same reason. I think it's an off-chance that this is possible, but please prove me wrong.

Comment: Never mind mine last comment even with InnoDB's online DDL you are looking into 6 hour downtime because you want to store the virtual column.. Besides do you really need to store the calculated/generated field?

Comment: I can't see your last commented anyway, so I don't mind it. I don't need to store it. But I need to access it without changing the ORM. I just googled some more and found that a generated virtual column pretty much fits my needs, but mysql says it doesn't know the syntax. I am looking into triggers right now.

Comment: accesing a generated column or a column that is "generated" by a trigger would also mean changing the select queries offcource by the way forgot to mention that..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found two ways to make this work:

1. Generated Columns:
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

I couldn't make them work myself, because the server's MySql version was below 5.7 and it is only supported from 5.7 onwards.

2. Trigger
   https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/

Here is a short example of how they can look.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_check BEFORE INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.active = 1 - NEW.deactivated;
```

That trigger automatically changes active to 1 - deactivated. Seeing that deactivated is either 0 or 1, it is always the exact opposite. I found this neat trick here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461135/9094259. Just in case anyone wants to give that guy an upvote. That does work quite well. But I am looking forward to the day where I can drop those triggers.

Cheers!

Comment: What happens if an insert sets `active` but does not set `deactivated`?

Comment: Also I would have used `SET NEW.active = NOT NEW.deactivated;` because I think that makes it more clear they are booleans.